# Is it possible to convert a switched light into a non-switched outlet?

Tags: wiring, switch, receptacle

I am installing an overhead automatic garage door opener.  My only power source close to where I will be hanging the motor is an overhead light socket that is operated by a switch on the wall next to the house entry door.  I wanted to know if it is possible to rewire the light socket with a standard electrical plug outlet AND to remove the switch & wire it to provide constant power to the new outlet.  The overhead light is on my 15A garage GFI circuit & the opener lists 120V/6A as its power requirements.

Thank you